# Disable Kmail running in background

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kmail

I was using Kmail for awhile on Kubuntu 16.04, but had to stop using it due to a few things I didn't like so I switched to Thunderbird.  Now that I don't want to use Kmail anymore I would also like to disable its notifications and stop it from running in the background.

Any easy way to do this without uninstalling?  I say that because they may fix a few of the problems which would make me want to use it again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kmail go to **Settings** menu, click on **Configure Kmail**, click on the account you do not want to "run in the background", click the **Modify** button in the right panel and uncheck **Enable interval mail checking.**